# How to parse INI-style config files using Config::General?

Tags: perl, ini

I understand that there are modules like `Config::Inifiles` and `Config::Simple` that I can use to parse ini-style configs.

But I was wondering if it's possible to configure `Config::General` to understand the format of .ini files as well.

If the ini file has only key-value pairs, then `Config::General` works fine, but it is not able to understand comments and section headers.

I tried parsing an ini file like:

```
; Config format
; [CONFIG_NAME]
; key1 = val1
; key2 = val2
; key3 = val3

[cat]
name = tom
likes = jerry

[mouse]
name = jerry
likes = cheese
```

but the output from `Config::General` is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '[mouse]' => '',
          'name' => [
                      'tom',
                      'jerry'
                    ],
          '[cat]' => '',
          'likes' => [
                       'jerry',
                       'cheese'
                     ],
          ';' => [
                   'Config format',
                   '[CONFIG_NAME]',
                   'key1 = val1',
                   'key2 = val2',
                   'key3 = val3'
                 ]
        };
```

Is there a way to tell `Config::General` to parse this correctly? Or is it a futile exercise, and I should switch to `Config::Inifiles`?

Comment: What is "correctly?" The [docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Config::General#COMMENTS) say these types of comments aren't supported, and yes, Config::IniFiles does allow you to specify an alternate "commentchar"

Comment: hi @obmib, i mean that the module should parse the config-file based on my specification. I went through the docs, and see that there is an enforcement of specific rules on the structure of the config which we can't change. I am using [Config::Any](http://search.cpan.org/~bricas/Config-Any-0.23/lib/Config/Any.pm) that recognizes several formats, so my problem for now is solved.

Comment: Can you please post your solution as an answer below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No: you cannot parse an ini file using Config::General. From its documentation, I have found that Config::General supports the parsing of a file that follows a certain set of rules only, and that we cannot configure it to read a different format, and I guess, that's the way it should be.

So, if you want to read an Apache-style config, or an rcfile having just key-value pairs, then [Config:General](http://search.cpan.org/~tlinden/Config-General-2.50/General.pm) is the module for you. But if you want to read an ini file, go for [Config::Inifiles](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.68/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm). Similarly, [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) helps in parsing XML files.

The main problem that I was trying to solve was this: I want to interact with a database resource using my perl script. I will get the database credentials, like the dbname, username, password etc. via a config file, but I don't (want to) have control over the format of the config, meaning the style/language should be transparent as long as the required keys are present in the config.

I found two modules that would work here: [Config::Any](http://search.cpan.org/~bricas/Config-Any-0.23/lib/Config/Any.pm) and [Config::Auto](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Config-Auto-0.42/lib/Config/Auto.pm). These are essentially wrappers around the language-specific Config::* modules. So, based on the structure of the config, they guess the type and parse accordingly.

I personally prefer Config::Auto as its syntax is less wordy, but both solve the problem!